# Detecting Metadata Requests from chat applications (Facebook messenger, WhatsApp, Slack, Teams, Telegram, ...)

Tags: http, metadata, chat

My web application requires authentication, therefore any non authenticated request is 302'ed to the login page of my application.

Users may share links to my application using their preferred social network, in that case most networks (mainly chat apps) will try to render a miniature using metadata.

Sadly they will have to work with the login page metadata.

To enrich the quality of user experience delivered by my application I would like to share the correct metadata.

As a result, I am looking for a way to detect requests coming from chats (Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp, Slack, Teams, etc.) so that I can offer them the correct metadata corresponding to the link shared.

Please note that the security concerns of sharing information to non authenticated users that way has already been considered and is not the subject of my question.

Comment: Hi @Filburt, may I inquire why you removed the greetings from my question ? Is it not a good thing to be polite here ?

Comment: The most important part of being polite here is writing good questions. It may seem somewhat rude to omit all greetings and thanks but is the agreed tone of conversation to leave out all this. See discussion on Meta [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/143302)